# Connecting to a Remote SQLCE or SQLite Database with Silverlight 4

Tags: database, silverlight-4.0, sqlite, sql-server-ce

Is there any way of connecting to a remote SQLCE or SQLite Database in Silverlight (4.0)?

If there is then please respond with links

Thanks

Please note that security is a non-issue in this scenario

Comment: What does remote mean in this context, remote in relation to the Silverlight client or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a sample here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/access-local-sql-compact-database-from.html or you can access a server hosted SQL Compact file over OData - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/06/walkthrough-expose-sql-compact-data-to.html